# Some threads in java cannot be killed while running on mac OS

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, selenium, teamcity

I am running selenium tests written in java on OSX through teamcity. For some reason , when all tests finishes to run , the agent failes to finish the build. I added some logs, and my guess is that it fails to kill some threads.

This are the threads running when the build starts:

```
system::Reference Handler::PRIORITY:-10::ThreadID::2
system::Finalizer::PRIORITY:-8::ThreadID::3
system::Signal Dispatcher::PRIORITY:-9::ThreadID::4
main::main::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::1
```

And this are the threads that runs when the build is finished:

```
system::Reference Handler::PRIORITY:-10::ThreadID::2
system::Finalizer::PRIORITY:-8::ThreadID::3
system::Signal Dispatcher::PRIORITY:-9::ThreadID::4
system::AppKit Thread::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::126
system::Java2D Queue Flusher::PRIORITY:-10::ThreadID::128
system::Java2D Disposer::PRIORITY:-10::ThreadID::129
system::process reaper::PRIORITY:-10::ThreadID::1136
main::main::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::1
main::New I/O  worker #89::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::253
main::New I/O  worker #90::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::254
main::New I/O  worker #91::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::255
main::New I/O  worker #92::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::256
main::New I/O server boss #12 ([id: 0xcaa62b3b, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:47629])::PRIORITY:-5::ThreadID::257
```

I ran the same exact program on windows, on multiple machines ,and I didn`t encounter any problem.In addition , in windows there are no extra threads when the build is finished.
Can any one help me please?
I have no clue about what is causing this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using Netty? Some suspect that these thread pile-ups are caused by a Netty bug: [one](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/issues/152), [two](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/592)